# Why is Python's subprocess' popen so different between unix and windows?

Tags: python, windows, unix, cross-platform, popen

I am trying to write cross-platform code in Python. The code should be spawning new shells and run code.

This lead me to look at Python's `subprocess` tool and in particular its `Popen` part. So I read through the documentation for this class [Popen doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and find too many "if on Unix/if on Windows" statements. Not very cross-platform, unless I have misunderstood the doc.

What is going on? I understand that the two operating systems are different, but really, there is no way to write a common interface? I mean, the same arguments "windows is different than unix" can be applied to `os`, `system`, etc., and they all seem 100 % cross-platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that process management is something deeply engrained in the operating system and differs greatly not only in the implementation but often even in the basic functionality. 
It's actually often rather easy to abstract code in for example the os class. Both C libraries, be it *nix or Windows, implement reading files as an I/O stream, so you can even write rather low level file operation functions which work the same in Windows and *nix.

But processes differ greatly. In *nix for example processes are all hierarchical, every process has a parent and all processes go back to the init system running under PID 1. A new process gets created by forking itself, checking if it's the parent or the child and then continuing accordingly. 
In Windows processes are strictly non-hierarchical and get created by the CreateProcess () system call, for which you need special privileges. 
There a good deal more differences, these were just two examples, but I hope it shows that implementing a platform independent process library is a very daunting task.

Comment: +1.  To add to that, probably the most important difference between Windows and Linux (in terms of implementing a library API for process management) is the way arguments are passed to the child.  Windows passes a single string representing the entire command line, and Linux passes an array of strings representing individual arguments.  That may not sound like a big deal, but can be if any of the arguments contain special characters.  Programmers frequently get caught out by this one.

Comment: Calling `CreateProcess` doesn't require special privileges, unless you're talking about running a process that needs elevation (in terms of the integrity level and enabled groups in the access token). The `appinfo` service provides access to the elevated access token. Typically you'd use `ShellExecute[Ex]` with the "runas" verb to access this service. Python's standard library has only minimal support for this via `os.startfile`. If the program is manifested to require elevation, you can use `Popen` with `shell=True`. Otherwise ctypes or PyWin32 is required.

Comment: Note also that `Popen.terminate` is very different on Windows. Since there's no OS support for Unix-style signals, the `terminate` method can't send a polite `SIGTERM` request that lets a program exit gracefully. It just calls `TerminateProcess` to immediately kill the process, i.e. the equivalent of the Unix `SIGKILL` signal. Instead of signals Windows has messages, such as `WM_CLOSE`. Also, since there's no process tree, `terminate` won't kill child processes. You need a Job object for this. Python's standard library has no support for Windows messages and jobs.